# Java: 401 Unauthorized test case issue in Unit test case for spring boot, REST

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, http-status-code-401, testcase

everyone.

I have written a test case:

**AppManagementApplicationTests.java**

```
@Test
public void testWithAppNameAsNull() {

    Input input = new Input();
    // input type
    String inputTrue = input.appNameAsNullOfAppInfo();
    // response has been stored
    Response response = Response.status(401).entity("").build();

    HttpEntity<String> passingData = new HttpEntity<String>(inputTrue);

    ResponseEntity<String> result = this.restTemplate.postForEntity("/App", passingData, String.class);
    assertEquals(response.getStatus(), result.getStatusCodeValue());

}
```

**Input.java**

```
public String appNameAsNullOfAppInfo() {
    String appName = null;
    String appVersion = "1.1";
    String appKey = "testkey";
    long timestamp = 1487076718;

    AppInfo obj = new AppInfo(appName, appVersion, appKey, timestamp);

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    // searialize into string and return
    return gson.toJson(obj);

}
```

In my code I am sending

> return new ResponseEntity(gson.toJson(response), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);

So when I run it using Postman it gives the status code as 401

[image]

But while testing it is giving an error
[image]

The URL that I am using is **http://localhost:8091/App/** and in the error it is showing **http://localhost:41636/App**.

And if instead of 401 UNAUTHORISED I change it to 400 BAD_REQUEST, the same test case works absolutely fine.
I am not able to figure out why. The line number 139 at which it is showing the error is **"ResponseEntity result ="**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a simple solution, just need to add a dependency in my 'pom.xml' file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now my test case is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2):

The url : http://localhost:8091/App/  is your app url defined by your server (Tomcat).

The url : http://localhost:41636/App is the one generated by the embedded server for your test case.. It gets created by the config webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT

Looking at your test, it doesn't look like an authentication issue, but it seems that the inputs parameters passed to your service are incorrect..

Comment: Thanks, @Teena. The input parameters that I am passing is correct, the thing that was missing was a dependency in my 'pom' file. After a lot of research I found one and now my test case is working absolutely fine.
Thanks once again for your help.